# Why is my gate driver simulations are taking very long?

Tags: simulation, ltspice, h-bridge, mosfet-driver, gate-driving

I want to turn on and turn off two mosfets from the asymmetric H bridge which is connected to SR motor at the same time.

I'm using IR2183 gate driver. The circuit connections from LTspice are show in the image. Why is my simulation taking very long? Is some thing wrong in my circuit?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "very long"? also, don't use ideal elements (like diodes) they make tons of problems.

Comment: The simulation is running very slow for this circuit. It took more than 5 mins to perform a time stop of 0.05 sec. From the simulation window I still see that the circuit is still running which is currently at 13us.

Comment: Of curiosity why do you use bootstrap on the low side switch? what is the point?

Comment: I was asked the same question by somebody else which made me think again. Now I'm working on the connections for the low side switching. I didn't mean to connect the bootstrap on low side switching. I only want to turn on both the mosfets at the same time.

Comment: @PlasmaHH That can be easily solved with `epsilon` (and/or `revepsilon`). The default "knee" is sharp and relies only on LTspice's internal solver to add 3 very small spaced points to try to make the derivative continuous, or at least no too "jumpy".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had great success increasing LTSpice simulation speed using the [convergence tips from ltwiki.org.](http://ltwiki.org/index.php5?title=Convergence_problems%3F)  Also, try adding a small series resistance, say 0.1 to 0.5 ohms, to the voltage sources.

If the simulation is only slow at the start, you can also try ramping the power supplies up from 0 to the final value using a PWL source instead of a hard turn on at t=0.  The ideal ramp time is circuit dependent, but 100uSec to 1ms is a reasonable range to try.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how that could help to my circuit. I followed  few suggestion from those tips but they didn't help. I guess in my case, I might have some problem with the values/components I chose.

Comment: Did you choose a specific diode model for your diodes?

Comment: I chose IN4148 and tried. But it didn't help

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the best diode, but that probably isn't the problem.  Do you have non-zero serial resistance on your voltage sources?

Comment: After your quick comment I added a serial resistance of 0.5 ohms for all the voltage sources. Doing so, I finally had a complete simulation.

Comment: Great!  Glad it worked

Comment: Thanks for that. I was scratching my dead for hours. Do I normally have to add a serial resistance of 0.5 ohms(which is the best value?) for all the voltage sources whenever I use them in my circuits?

Comment: It really depends on how hard the circuit is for the solver.  Anything with large transients is harder to solve.  0.5 ohms is reasonable.  I generally start with 0.1 ohms to see if it has an effect.

Comment: Okay. I will keep it in mind for my future circuits. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: 1n4148 is low-current diode with large series bulk resistance. I can use it, but edit that param to be 1 ohm, to allow large forward currents.

Comment: @crj11 The voltage source, if it doesn't have parasitics specified (Rpar, Cpar), it behaves like a voltage source, with zero internal resistance. LTspice's matrix solver uses MNA, so current sources are preferred (also mentioned in the manual). Adding Rser or Cpar makes LTspice convert internally the voltage source to a current source with a shunt resistor Rser (+Cpar, if added). In this case, I suspect even a Rser=1m (and/or Cpar=1m, or the likes) would have helped.