# How can I simulate a Infineon IR2183 gate driver in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice, boost, h-bridge, spice, gate-driving

I'm making a boost converter in LTspice, initially with ideal switches and comparators, but now trying to use realistic components.

For the MOSEFT I just picked one from the available ones that has a low on resistance and small gate capacitance.

The gate drives is a bit more tricky, as they don't seem to come included with LTspice. So I went on the hunt on the web, and found that Infineon provides (unencrypted!) spice models.

I downloaded the MicroSim Pspice model for the IR2183 (also used [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/357319/why-is-my-gate-driver-simulations-are-taking-very-long)) from the [Infineon product page](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/gate-driver-ics/half-bridge-drivers/ir2183/), and have LTspice generate a symbol by right-clicking in the `.sub` file.

I made a little test schematic, like in the picture below, but the HO and LO outputs are stuck at respectively 5V and 0V. I have so far tried IR2183, IR2181, and IR2101 based on both the PSpice and OrCad files. All of them produce identical results: nothing.

I'm not tied to any particular driver or even manufacturer, so if there is a way to make this gate driver work, great, if there is another manufacturer that produces gate drivers and corresponding spice files, also fine.

[image: LTspice circuit]

Comment: Recommended minimum operating voltage for that device is 10 volts. I'm not saying that is the problem but try lifting the supply to 10 volts from 5 volts.

Comment: Linear actually makes gate drivers too, and they are available from LTSpice: LTC4441, LTC1693, ...

Comment: try these models, only for ltspice http://ltwiki.org/files/LTspiceIV/examples/LtSpicePlus/Smps/Ir21xx/IR2184_Hierarch/

Comment: This is why LTSpice is free: The LTC4446 works fine, so now Linear technology is getting my business rather than Infineon because I'm too lazy to mess with their model.

Comment: Except the LTC4446 is not available at Farnell...